# 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket (vsftpd in raspbian)

Tags: linux

I configured the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file then `restart` the `vsftpd` service. And when I go to check the `vsftpd`'s running status, it returns:

```
500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket
```

I have done a lot of research before I coming here. And almost everyone gives a solution which is stop the `inetd` server (conflict with standalone mode or something... well... I am not sure). However, in my case there is nothing called the `inetd`.

And there are some other things. Someone said that it is about one line `listen=NO` 
.

> If this is `NO` it will run from `inetd` (which I do not have one)

The status is:

```
00 OOPS: vsftpd: not configured for standalone, must be started from inetd
```

> If this is `YES` it will run in `standalone` mode

The status is:

```
500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket
```

I do not know how to fix is. Please help me.

---

BTW, the system info is as follows:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing `systemd` and `sysV` commands. Don't just tell us what doesn't work. Tell us WHAT YOU HAVE DONE, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Milliways I would like to know what's matter with the `systemd` or `sysV`?

Comment: Jessie uses `systemd` rather than the older `sysV `. The difference is too complex to explain here, but if you google you will find thousands of articles (many ill-informed). That doesn't change the fact that unless you explain what you are trying to do no one can help.

Comment: @Milliways okay. What I am try to do is build a ftp server by using vsftpd. And here comes the error. That's al

Comment: Raspbian already has a `ftp` server. All you need to do is connect to it.

Comment: @Milliways I will uninstall vsftpd then try connecting ftp

Answer (score 2):

### Another Program Has Bound Port 21

Use this command to see all programs bound to network ports:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -lnpt --protocol=inet
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      397/sshd
```

The above output on my fresh install of `2016-03-18-rasbian-jessie` shows that I'm running one program:

- `sshd`   bound to port `22`

Look for a program bound to port `21` and kill it, then try starting `vsftpd` again with:

```
sudo systemctl start vsftpd.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure vsftpd` and choose standalone mode.

Comment: Could you expand on this a little.  How would it help?